# How to make pathfinding to character smoother

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local PathFinding = game:GetService("PathfindingService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local RunServices = game:GetService("RunService")

local Enemy = script.Parent
local Humanoid = Enemy:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
Enemy.PrimaryPart:SetNetworkOwner(nil)

local waypoints
local nextWaypointIndex
local reachedConnection
local blockedConnection

local walkspeed = Enemy:GetAttribute("Walkspeed")
local sprintspeed = Enemy:GetAttribute("sprintspeed")
local damage = Enemy:GetAttribute("damage")

local function getPath(destination)
    local path = PathFinding:CreatePath({
        AgentHeight = 6;
        AgentRadius = 3;
        AgentCanJump = false;
        AgentCanClimb = false;
        
        Costs = {
            Water = 100;
            DangerZone = math.huge
        }
    })
    
    path:ComputeAsync(Enemy.HumanoidRootPart.Position, destination.Position)
    
    return path
end

local function findTarget()
    local neareastTarget
    local maxDistance = 50
    
    for index, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers())do
        if player.Character then
            local target = player.Character
            local distance = (Enemy.HumanoidRootPart.Position - target.HumanoidRootPart.Position).Magnitude
            
            if distance < maxDistance then
                neareastTarget = target
                maxDistance = distance
            end
        end
    end
    return neareastTarget
end

local function Capture(target)
    local distance = (Enemy.HumanoidRootPart.Position - target.HumanoidRootPart.Position).Magnitude

    if distance > 3 then
        local charPath = getPath(target.HumanoidRootPart)
        for _, waypoint in ipairs(charPath:GetWaypoints()) do
            Humanoid:MoveTo(waypoint.Position)
            Humanoid.MoveToFinished:Wait()
        end
    else
        target.Humanoid:TakeDamage(damage)
    end
end

local function walkTo(destination)
    local path = getPath(destination)
    
    if path.Status == Enum.PathStatus.Success then
        for index, waypoint in pairs(path:GetWaypoints())do
            local target = findTarget()
            
            if target then
                Capture(target)
                Enemy.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = sprintspeed
                break
            else 
                Enemy.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = walkspeed
                Humanoid:MoveTo(waypoint.Position)
                Humanoid.MoveToFinished:Wait()
            end
        end
    else 
        Humanoid:MoveTo(destination.Position - (Enemy.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame.LookVector * 10))
    end
end

local function Patrol()
    local waypoints = workspace.WayPoints:GetChildren()
    local randomWaypoint = math.random(1, #waypoints)
    walkTo(waypoints[randomWaypoint])
end

while wait(0.01) do
    Patrol()
end
```

I'm trying to make a pathfinding enemy to capture and kill the player, but the problem I'm having is that it doesn't run as smoothly as expected, it looked like it's updating the position of the player but it stops until that current position has been reached. If there's a way to constantly chase the player without stopping that will be great